# Am having Issues with zend framework redirecting to Homepage

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework, frameworks

good day all, am sorry if am not on the correct page for asking this. am new here.

I got a script from a client to setup (codecayon clone)  "Built with zend framework" Installation done successfully,HOME page works, But if i click on any menu link or pages, it still show me home page. Please help me How can i fix this?.I not used zend framework before,  you can check the site URL http://www.naijakonga.com.ng

thanks.

Comment: You didn't add links to the hrefs

Comment: Hi, thanks for respond, but please explain more.
thanks.

Comment: Does you have used routes in your code for menu links?